# Yolo confusion matrix - Background Class

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, cnn, yolo

I am training the yoloV5 model, where, I have two class[object = A and B].

In the dataset, the class `B` has more samples than class `A`

I get to know, to reduce false positive, we have to add around 10% of background images. So, I made added the background images which does not have the `A` ad `B` objects, only in training dataset not in validation dataset

Then i trained the model

I get this result for the best model

```
metrics/precision       0.99232
metrics/recall          0.99164
metrics/mAP_0.5         0.99486
metrics/mAP_0.5:0.95    0.93233
x/lr0                   0.000694
x/lr1                   0.000694
x/lr2                   0.000694

                                                    
train/box_loss          0.011185
val/box_loss            0.0098416

train/obj_loss          0.0093163
val/obj_loss            0.0057613

train/cls_loss          0.0003447
val/cls_loss            1.1311E-05
```

In test dataset, the model is good to detect the two objects[object A and object B], but in some samples, the model predicted the other object[we can refer this unwanted object as class `C` which is not annotated in the training/val dataset and also this object has one or two samples in the train and val dataset] as object `B` which is False Positive.

In confusion matrix,
[image]

Here, The background class is predicted as object `B`.

By looking the train and val loss, the model is not overfitted, if it is overfitted, then the val loss is higher that the train loss, but, in this case, the val loss is less than train loss.

How the background class is predicted as other class, What are the possible reasons?
And, how to solve